# How to create solid extrusion of bitmap with OpenGL?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl, vector, bitmap

I have a bitmap image (RGB, no alpha), like the image below (letter 'R'):

[image]

Which is the best way, with OpenGL & VC++, to create the extrusion of the bitmap? Parameter is a 3f vector. Either solid extrusion or surface only extrusion is ok.

Any idea?

Comment: OpenGL is not going to help you here. You're going to have to generate this on the CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like said so often: OpenGL is "merely" a drawing API, rasterizing triangles to the screen. It doesn't deal with scenes. It doesn't deal with geometry.

Extrusion of a bitmap requires two specific tasks, neither of which OpenGL can do for you: Vectorizing the outline. Extruding the outline. The hard part is vectorizing, extrusion of a planar, closed path is simple.

Answer (score 0):

I have one solution, but it utilises the texture 3D feature to make solid extrusion so it is truely slow:

"Duplicate the bitmap data (pixel data) by vector length to create 3D texture"

However, this is only perpendicular extrusion (perpendicular vector), and frankly, it's slow.

Comment: You gain nothing from converting your 2D texture in a 3D texture. Frankly you're just wasting memory, since you can have the same effect by projecting the 3rd texture coordinate to 0. 3D textures don't give you volumetric objects, that's not how they work. A 3D texture allow you to grab "slices" out of a volume to apply to a flat primitive.